# how to modify the properties of a button knowing its name and tag? (objective c)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button, properties, tags

What would be the code to modify the properties of a button (that was created programmatically) knowing its name and tag. (the amount of buttons created isn't always the same, that's why i assigned a tag to the buttons created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `viewWithTag:`

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
//then change the properties
[btn setTitle:@"Press Me" forState:UIControlState];
//etc etc
```

The advantage of this is that if you have multiple buttons with the same changes you can easily loop through the different buttons

```
for (int i=0; i<numberOfButtons; i++) {
     UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:i+1];
     [btn setTitle:@"Press Me" forState:UIControlState];
     //etc etc
}
```

This assumes your tags start from 1 and increment.

Comment: Thanks you, this way to do it is great! :)

Answer (score 0):

All you really need to identify a button is its tag. The code would look something like:

```
if (button.tag == 2) {
    button.titleLabel.text = @"New text";
    button.enabled = NO;
    // etc...
}
```

Merely place that into whatever function you want to change your button(s) in.